# Kotlin: Enum companion function

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to extend the Enum companion object with a simple function as follows:

```
fun Enum.Companion.myFun() = 1
```

However when I try to call it on an Enum `State`, it is unknown to Kotlin.

```
State.myFun()
```

I can see it works for `Enum.myFun()`, but that is not what I need.

Comment: Is state an instance of the class Enum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is sadly not possible. You'd have to declare a companion for `State` and any other subclass separately.

[Extensions are resolved **statically**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically)

> We would like to emphasize that extension functions are dispatched **statically**, i.e. they are not virtual by receiver type. This means that the extension function being called is determined by the type of the expression on which the function is invoked, not by the type of the result of evaluating that expression at runtime.

Additionally `companion object` are not virtual either. A subclass won't ever be able to access the companion of the super class.

[Companion Objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

> The name of a class used by itself (not as a qualifier to another name) acts as a reference to the companion object of the class (whether named or not).

Comment: That is very sad :/

Comment: looks like compiler/language limitation that should be addressed or not permitted at all imho because why they allow it to be defined if it cannot be used ?